# Cannot use GraphQLSchema from another module or realm in NextJS 14

Tags: next.js, graphql

(Creating this because I searched for ages and then found an answer)

I wanted to use type-graphql together with apollo-server-lambda and nextjs (because I wanted to use nextjs api routes for local developmnt, while having lambdas serving my API in production).

I got the error:

```
Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema [...] from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the
node_modules directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the
dependencies of other relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure
only one version is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple things.

What finally solved the problem was adding

```
experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["graphql"],
},
```

to my `next.config.js` file.

Other things I tried:

- Making sure that I only have one version of graphql installed (was 15.8.0)
- changing the webpack config (this just crashed my nextjs installation)